# What is the most efficient and scalable equivalent of grepping a string on a website using curl in Golang?

Tags: curl, memory, go, grep, scalability

**Background**

```
user@host curl -s http://stackoverflow.com | grep -m 1 stackoverflow.com
```

returns immediately if the string is found:

```
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
```

**Aim**

find a string on a website using Golang

**Method**

Based on sources from [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/regular-expressions) and [Schier's Blog](http://schier.co/blog/2015/04/26/a-simple-web-scraper-in-go.html) the following code was created:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://stackoverflow.com"
    resp, _ := http.Get(url)
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("stackoverflow.com")
    fmt.Println(r.FindString(string(bytes)))
    resp.Body.Close()
}
```

**Results**

Running the code results in:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

**Discussion & Conclusions**

1. More code is required to achieve the same aim in Golang or is there a shorter solution
2. Both options seems to return at the same time. Is static code in this case faster than dynamic code as well?
3. I am concerned whether this code consumes too much memory. It should be used eventually to monitor hundreds of different websites

Comment: I'd be willing to bet bytes.Index is both the most concise and performant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code implements grep, stopping at the first line that contains the given string. It avoids reading the entire webpage into memory at once by using a `bufio.Scanner`, which apart from bounding the memory use might also speed up the program in the case where the string is found near the start of a huge page. It's careful to use `scan.Bytes()` to avoid converting every line into a string, which would cause significant memory churn.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://stackoverflow.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to open url")
    }
    scan := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
    toFind := []byte("stackoverflow.com")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    for scan.Scan() {
        if bytes.Contains(scan.Bytes(), toFind) {
            fmt.Println(scan.Text())
            return
        }
    }
}
```